# change partitioning in HANA?

Tags: primary-key, hana, partition

I have created a table and partitioned it with the round robin method in SAP HANA. I have loaded the data into the table and now I cannot add the primary key for the table since it is a round robin partition. Is there any way to add primary key for this table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to re-partition the table to a form that allows for primary keys.